# Serialize an object with array in Avro

Tags: java, avro

I need to serialize an object with an `Object[]` field in it into a byte array, but when I execute the following code the result byte array is empty:

```
TestObject testObject = new TestObject();

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DatumWriter<TestObject> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<TestObject>(TestObject.class);
final Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().directBinaryEncoder(out, null);

writer.write(testObject, encoder);
out.close();
// This is empty
byte[] res = out.toByteArray();
```

Where TestObject is:

```
class TestObject {
    Object[] arr = new Object[] {1, "str", false};
}
```

If I replace TestObject definition with:

```
class TestObject {
    String str = "str";
}
```

It works fine and I see that the `String` field is successfully written to the byte array.

Does Avro has any issues with serializing `Object[]` arrays or do I use it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the reflected schema that is generated assumes all your objects in the array are of type Object.
If you want them to be Integer, String or Boolean, I don't think that you will be able to use reflection, but to define the schema yourself.
If your array will of String, for example, it **will** work.